# Object oriented JavaScript help

Tags: javascript, singleton, oop, closures

I have the following code:

```
var HD = function() { };

HD.Car = (function() {
    var _date = "09/07/2010";
    return {
        Make: undefined,
        Model: undefined,
        showMakeAndModel: function() {
            document.write(this.Make + " " + 
                           this.Model + 
                           " (data correct as of " + _date + ")");
            }
        };
    })();

var bert = new HD.Car();
bert.Make = "Ford";
bert.Model = "Capri";
window.onload = bert.showMakeAndModel();
```

And get the following error:

> HD.Car is not a constructor

All I'm trying to do is test (to learn) the 'singleton pattern' with closure (for private members) so not a 'real' example, but the book I'm reading suggests this is the way to do it.

So a little confused - any help would be much appreciated..
Rob

Comment: Apologies to anyone reading this page. I can't delete it although I want to now! Unfortunately a couple of the contributors have rendered this post unusable.

I will post the same question again shortly if anyone still feels like helping. I will add the link here once an answer exists.

MODERATORS - feel free to delete this post.

Comment: we've solved your problem and you say "contributors have rendered this post unusable"?

Comment: galambalazs - yes you have all contributed to answering the question although it's not quite answered. Yours and David's answers are nearest to the mark. However the problem here is that this has turned into a discussion - Stack is not a discussion forum for the exact reason that people coming to the page after should not have to wade through a discussion (or argument in this case) to find the answer. That's why, in my opinion, this post is almost useless. Not your fault though mate, and I really appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 3):

You have some incorrect ()() around the HD.Car class definition. This fixed sample works:

```
var HD = function() { }; 

HD.Car = function() { 
    var _date = "09/07/2010"; 
    return { 
        Make: undefined, 
        Model: undefined, 
        showMakeAndModel: function() { 
            document.write(this.Make + " " +  
                           this.Model +  
                           " (data correct as of " + _date + ")"); 
            } 
        }; 
    }; 

var bert = new HD.Car(); 
bert.Make = "Ford"; 
bert.Model = "Capri"; 
window.onload = bert.showMakeAndModel();
```

Comment: Constructors shouldn't return anything.

Comment: I agree, however, I believe he is using the pattern where return is used to ensure if it is accidently called as a function, it has the same result.

Comment: Yes, but the attributes `Make` and `Model` you assign will not refer to the attributes of the `HD.Car` instance, rather they are just attributes of the `bert` namespace.

Comment: Luca I think you might be on to something here as the intellisense (VS) is not picking up "bert.showMakeAndModel()" - however, firstly this does work, and secondly, "_date" works as a private member. I do need a solution where "bert.showMakeAndModel()" appears in intellisense though...

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9, I don't feel like helping you anymore, please read a book.

Comment: *"Yes, but the **attributes** Make and Model you assign will not refer to the attributes of the HD.Car instance, rather they are just attributes of the bert **namespace**. "* and *"I don't feel like helping you anymore, please read a book"* - that's hilarious...

Comment: @ Luca Matteis 1.) they are properties not attributes. 2.) there are no namespaces in the language 3.) a constructor function returns an object reference, just as the example above. *"Constructors shouldn't return anything"* - constructors return *this* by default. But you can return another object, then the default will be garbage collected. This is how you emulate private variables in js. 4.) read a book yourself

Answer (score 1):

For a bit more info:

[How to write a singleton class in javascript](http://www.javascriptkata.com/2009/09/30/how-to-write-a-singleton-class-in-javascript/).

Hopefully that will shed a bit more light for you!

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** `new`, because it is only needed for constructor functions. Now HD.Car will be the **object** that an **anonymous and self-executing** function **returns**. Then remove parens after HD.Car. So it should look like:

```
var bert = HD.Car;
```

Now HD.Car is a `singleton`.

If you want it to be more like a `factory` you should do:

```
HD.Car = function() {
    var _date = "09/07/2010";
    return {
        Make: undefined,
        Model: undefined,
        showMakeAndModel: function() {
            document.write(this.Make + " " + 
                           this.Model + 
                           " (data correct as of " + _date + ")");
        }
   };
};​

var bert = new HD.Car();
```

Comment: HD.Car is not a regular function... it's an object.

Comment: **every function is an object**. A regular function means that it is not a constructor function. Read before comment.

Comment: no, a function is not an object. If you're referring to the ability of doing `HD.something`, this is possible because `HD` is simply a namespace, not because it's a function. In fact `var HD = 3; HD.something = 4` will work also simply because JavaScript offers the ability to add attributes to namespaces, even if they're not objects.

Comment: :) ok 2 things here. I've misread the code above I should correct. But your last statement is still false. Functions are objects in js...

Comment: @galambalazs, again no, take a look at the `typeof` operator.

Comment: you mean the typeof operator which returns `object` even for `null`. The typeof operator doesn't really tell much about the language. **Functions are first-class objects in Javascript**. Learn to live with it.

Comment: What's wrong with `null` being an object? I'm not sure I can trust your un-referenceable answers.

Comment: You want lmgtfy??? **"Every function in JavaScript is actually a Function object." (mdc)** - source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function

Comment: `I'm not sure I can trust your un-referenceable answers.` ahahahaa xD

Comment: Functions in JavaScript are not of type Object. They are however implemented as objects. Implementation is different than Definition. Just how in `var a = 3;` a is not an Object, it's a Number. However the Number type is implemented as an Object. This has NOTHING to do with the question at hand so stop introducing extra overhead to the argument.

Comment: *"However the Number type is implemented as an Object."* `var f = function(){}; f.prop = 5` vs `var a = 3; a.prop = 5`.

Comment: But as a last "un-reference" you could read wikipedia: JavaScript. *"Functions are first-class; they are objects themselves"*

Comment: If functions are treated as type 'object' then why can't you use the keyword `new` on all objects? again, we're not talking of how things are implemented in Javascript, rather how they work, and why it's important to understand the `type` of things (the `typeof` operator is not useless as you think).

Comment: I didn't say it's useless (nonsense sometimes? yes). But i'ts hilarious how you treat `typeof` as a language specification`. But why the heck you keep saying implementation? Hello! We're talking about a language here. :)

Comment: You should treat `typeof` as a language specification, stop confusing people.

Comment: Let's see the **language specification** says: `(4.3.11) Null Value: The null value is a primitive value that represents the null, empty, or non-existent reference.`, and **`Null Type: The type Null has exactly one value, called null.`** And yet **`typeof null`** will give you **object**. This indicates that **you've never read the specification**, and you're misinformed probably by one of the awful books out there.

Comment: I gave you **three** references and you called my statements "un-referenceable". Now, you show me some references of your misconceptions... But other than the actual specification they can only be the misconceptions of other people...

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can only use the **new** keyword with **functions**.

`HD.Car` is not a function, it's an object.

Just don't use `new` for your example.

Comment: How can I instansiate a new HD.Car object without the 'new' keyword?

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 you can use new, and instansiate see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from the fact that you're executing your constructor function, as indicated by the open and close parentheses after the declaration of HD.Car (and just before var bert). So, the function is executing and returning an object, which you're then trying to use with the "new" operator.

If you remove those parentheses, I believe you'll get the functionality you want.